# How can I ensure version consistency of duplicated dependencies in a Javascript monorepo?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a Javascript (Typescript) monorepo. Each of my packages has its own `package.json` where it defines dependencies. Some of those external dependencies might be duplicated in more than one package.

```
repo/
├── package.json
├── packageA
│   └── package.json
│         dependencies: [
│           "libA": "^1.0.0",
│           "libB": "^1.0.0"
│         ]
├── packageB
│   └── package.json
│         dependencies: [
│           "libC": "^1.0.0"
│         ]
└── packageC
    └── package.json
          dependencies: [
            "libA": "^1.0.0" <-- duplicated with packageA
          ]
```

Sometimes (for instance, when using `yarn workspace packageC libA`) I inadvertently get a different version of, say, `libA` in two of my packages:

```
repo/
├── package.json
├── packageA
│   └── package.json
│         dependencies: [
│           "libA": "^1.0.0",
│           "libB": "^1.0.0"
│         ]
├── packageB
│   └── package.json
│         dependencies: [
│           "libC": "^1.0.0"
│         ]
└── packageC
    └── package.json
          dependencies: [
            "libA": "^2.0.0" <-- different version than packageA's
          ]
```

Sometimes these mismatches are harmless. Sometimes they throw errors that I can immediately spot. But sometimes they cause subtle bugs in my app that I waste a lot of time tracking down. So, except in very rare cases, *I never want to have different versions of a given package in my monorepo*.

I'd like to have some sort of guard rail that will keep me from having different versions installed unless I really want them. Is there a best practice for this? I have no idea what form that might take. Here are some possibilities:

- pulling any shared library up to the top-level `package.json`. (I have a large number of packages in the monorepo. If only a couple of them need `libA`, are there negative consequences for build size or whatever if I pull `libA` to the top level?)
- running some kind of version check at some stage of the build process that issues warnings for mismatches
- a yarn hook (?) that checks versions when I run `yarn add` and warns me if I'm installing a different one
- using a third-party tool introducing another layer of indirection to define common versions across packages
- something else I haven't thought of

Comment: I'd just use a single package.json and put all dependencies in the parent. When building your builder will parse the import/require statements in your code so won't just simply copy the entire node_modules folder

Comment: This is something you can handle in CI or in git hooks, etc — on every commit, traverse the filesystem for all valid package files and compare versions.

Comment: This might be a better fit for the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site.

Comment: @jsejcksn A git hook is definitely a possibility here (and might be the best answer) but it means I still may miss the silent insidious bugs if I'm working on a change for a while without committing anything. The ideal place for the hook would be in the `yarn` (or `npm`) command, but [yarn hooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=yarn+hooks) don't really cover this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [syncpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/syncpack). It will do the basics of what you want by making sure that dependencies are consistent across all package.json files in a given monorepo.

You could use it with a git hook (we use [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky)) or via an npm script.