# How can I tell `yarn workspace` to refer to executables at the root of my JavaScript monorepo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I have a large JavaScript (TypeScript) monorepo with many subpackages:

```
root/
  package.json
  packages/
    packageA/
      package.json
    packageB/
      package.json
    ...
    packageZ/
      package.json
```

Libraries that I share across all subpackages are defined in `root/package.json`, two examples being vitest and typescript:

**root/package.json:**

```json
...
"private": true,
"workspaces": [
  "packages/*"
],
"devDependencies": {
  "typescript": "^4.0.0",
  "vitest": "^1.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "^4.0.0"
}
```

So far, so good. The code in the subpackages (workspaces) has access to the libraries defined at the root; e.g., I can call lodash functions.

But say I then want to define a script in a subpackage:

**packageA/package.json:**

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "vitest $*",
  "build": "tsc --build"
}
```

If I try to run these scripts from a workspace, I get errors because yarn doesn't know how to find the executable:

```
$ yarn workspace packageA test
command not found: vitest
$ yarn workspace packageA build
command not found: tsc
```

Ok, I can define the dependencies directly in `packageA`:

**packageA/package.json:**

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "vitest $*",
  "build": "tsc --build"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "typescript": "^4.0.0",
  "vitest": "^1.0.0"
}
```

Now yarn is fine with it:

```
$ yarn workspace packageA test
... stuff happens ...
$ yarn workspace packageA build
... stuff happens ...
```

... but I don't want to define these dependencies once for every subpackage (dozens of times) if I can help it. I'd rather define them once, at the root, both for simplicity and to ensure I'm [always running exactly the same version in every package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722600/how-can-i-ensure-version-consistency-of-duplicated-dependencies-in-a-javascript).

Is there a way to make this work? How can I refer to these executables at the root from a yarn workspace?

Comment: Is your  root `package.json` correctly defining workspaces? As in 
```json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Correct @VonC - I have those two settings in the root `package.json` as you specified. (I edited the question to show that.) In most respects `yarn workspace` seems to work fine.